# Sending to header location even though previous form incorrect

Tags: php

I have the code below set-up. The user simply enters their email address, clicks the submit button and then should be taken to the next page. The problem is that even if they haven't entered an email it will still take them to that page I know its probably a stupid error but I just can't seem to spot it.

```
?php
include('header.php');
include('side.php'); ?>

<div id="content">

<?php
if($_SESSION['uid'] != 1)

echo '
<h2>Alpha Registration</h2>
<p align="center">Registration for an Alpha Account costs &#163;5.<br>You will be asked to confirm and pay on the following page.</p>
<form method="post" action="alpharegister.php">
<div id="loginform"><center><table>
<tr><td>Email:</td><td><input type="text" class="box" name="email"></td></tr>
<tr><td colspan="2"><center><input type="submit" class="submit" name="registersubmit" value="Begin Registration"></center></td></tr>
</table></center></div></form>';

else {
}

if($_POST['registersubmit'] && (isset($_POST['email'] && isempty($_POST['email'])){
$email = protect($_POST['email']);

if(!$email) {
echo '<div class="incorrectlogin">You must enter a valid email address.</div>';
}else{

$checkemail = "/^[a-z0-9]+([_\\.-][a-z0-9]+)*@([a-z0-9]+([\.-][a-z0-9]+)*)+\\.[a-z]{2,}$/i";

if(!preg_match($checkemail, $email)) {
echo '<div class="incorrectlogin">You must enter a valid email address.</div>';
}else{

setcookie("AlphaEmail", $email, time()+3600);
header('Location: alpharegister.php');
}}}?>
```

EDIT
Edited code above to show full index.php including the code that was suggested below.

alpharegister.php

```
<?php
include('header.php');
include('side.php');
?>

<div id="content">
<h1>Alpha Account Registration</h1>

<?php
echo 'Your email is ' .$_COOKIE["AlphaEmail"]. '!';
?>

<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="FJP9C8CSJ73GG">
<input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/GB/i/btn/btn_buynowCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal – The safer, easier way to pay online.">
<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_GB/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>
</div>
```

Comment: Just add additional condition, to check if email is get set.  if($_POST['registersubmit'] && isset($_POST['email']) ) { }

Comment: I presume you do have `session_start();` in there right?

Comment: Yes I have it in my header.php. Oh and I have tried the coding bug it still takes you to that page, just without any info on it. Plus it brings up an error: undefined function for isempty.

Comment: @user2759865 What type of function is this `$email = protect($_POST['email']);` `protect`? I've never seen that before. Unless you have a function called `protect`, is invalid as far as I'm concerned. I think you want to do is `$email = $_POST['email'];`

Comment: I do have that function set, but tried it without it and it still takes me to the header location.

Comment: You need to post your full and actual code then. It's hard for me tell. And I don't see anything in your posted code about any `if(empty...`. Show me what's inside `alpharegister.php` the problem is most likely in there.

Comment: You need to change this `&& isempty($_POST['email'])){` to `&& empty($_POST['email'])){` `isempty` is not a PHP function. Change that and try it again then let me know.

Comment: Thought so, but have already tried it and its still taking me to alpharegister.php

Comment: Ok, you had it backwards. Try this `if(isset($_POST['registersubmit']) && empty($_POST['email'])){` the `if(isset` is for the `submit` button.

Comment: Tried it, still taking me to alpharegister.php. At this point I may give it up.

Comment: Actually you have `else { }` with nothing inside it above `if($_POST['registersubmit']` try removing it.

Comment: Getting the same result.

Comment: and you have `session_start();` inside EVERY file?

Comment: And I assume this is a typo `?php
include('header.php');`? Missing `<` in `?php`

Comment: session_start(); and ob_start(); are in the header.php file so yes they are in every file. And yes it is a typo, missed its when copied.

Comment: I don't know what else is could be then. *baffled*

Answer (score 1):

Added this additional conditional statement , to check the email input value is enter or not

```
if($_POST['registersubmit'] && (isset($_POST['email']) && !isempty($_POST['email']) )) {
// do you stuff here
}
```